# Unable to do a search using tag

Tags: tags, search-builder

When doing a contact search using tags from search builder Civi throws DB syntax error, this was working before until Civi upgraded to 5.35.1

[image]

Error:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(contact_a.sort_name, 1) as sort_name\n
               FROM civicrm_contact contact_a    LEFT JOIN civicrm_entity_tag `civicrm_entity_tag-60788273efd52` ON ( `civicrm_entity_tag-60788273efd52`.entity_id = contact_a.id  AND `civicrm_entity_tag-60788273efd52`.entity_table = &#039;civicrm_contact&#039;)  \n
              WHERE  (  ( `civicrm_entity_tag-60788273efd52`.tag_id IN (  ) )  )  AND ( 1 ) AND (contact_a.is_deleted = 0) [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near &#039;) )  )  AND ( 1 ) AND (contact_a.is_deleted = 0)&#039; at line 3]
        &quot;&quot;&quot;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check if the tag you selected is a parent tag and has child tags? If yes than this is a known bug on 5.35.1 when doing a search on parent tag and is logged at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2502 and is fixed as part of 5.38 release.

Solution(one of the below):

1. Use 'IN' operator instead of '='.
2. Apply patch from [here](https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/19961.patch).
3. Wait for 5.38.0 release

Comment: Thanks for your help, the patch fixed the problem for us